# HTML5 validation

Tags: forms, html, validation

I wonder if HTML5 have any formvalidation for dual entry (write 2 identical password) and can you write own exceptions?

Thanx in advance!

Comment: While you can do this, you should really avoid this. Do the validation on server side via Ajax.

Answer (score 24):

If you want something a bit nicer and HTML5-utilising, try this:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/html5forms/

```
<label>Password:</label>
<input type="password" id="password" name="password">
<label>Confirm Password:</label>
<input type="password" id="passwordconf" name="passwordconf" oninput="check(this)">
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
function check(input) {
    if (input.value != document.getElementById('password').value) {
        input.setCustomValidity('The two passwords must match.');
    } else {
        // input is valid -- reset the error message
        input.setCustomValidity('');
   }
}
</script>
```

Make it fancy by adding this to your CSS (below).  It puts a red border around the offending input fields when they fail HTML5 validation.

```
:invalid {
     border: 2px solid #ff0000;
}
```

All done.  You should still use an alert() or server-side validation to ensure that the user inputs both passwords correctly.  Don't rely on client-side anything.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, and to solve it using the HTML5 api I did this: setted a pattern for the password to contain at least eight letters and a number. Then to make them matching I did:

```
    var password = document.querySelector('#password'),
        passwordConfirm = document.querySelector('#password_confirm');

    [].forEach.call([password, passwordConfirm], function(el) {
        el.addEventListener('input', function() {
            if (!el.validity.patternMismatch) {
                if ( password.value === passwordConfirm.value ) {
                    try{password.setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}
                } else {
                    password.setCustomValidity("Password and password confirm doesn\'t match")
                }
            }
        }, false)
    });
```

where with `el.validity.patternMismatch` check for the pattern validity first and then check for the validity of the two.
Here is my password input with the pattern.

`<input type="password" pattern="^((?=.*(\d|\W))(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,})$" id="password" />`

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite sure that's not possible. Also, it can be easily covered by javascript so why not use that instead?

This works perfectly well:

```
<script language="javascript"> 
function checkPassword() { 
    if (document.pwForm.pw1.value != document.pwForm.pw2.value) { 
        alert ('The passwords do not match!');
        return false; 
    } 
} 
</script>
<form action="filename.ext" name="pwForm" method="GET/POST">
    <input type="password" name="pw1" value=""><br />
    <input type="password" name="pw2" value=""><br />
    <input type="Submit" name="CheckPassword" value="Check Passwords" onClick="return checkPassword();">
</form>
```

Comment: Although the answer is right. This code has a lot problems: 1. If field1 is not changed the custom error isn't added. 2. if someone has mistyped the password in pw1 and not in pw2 and changes this after the field stays invalid although it's valid). 3. Changing the custom validity should be only made, if the field hasn't already a custom error or the custom error was added by the same script (you need to test the validity.customError/validationMessage for this)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Kicker, that was really useful.

I extended it a little to make the password and password confirm inputs to be invalid as soon as typing in the input started.

```
var password = document.querySelector(' input[name=usr_password]');
var passwordConfirm = document.querySelector(' input[name=usr_password_confirm]');
if (password && passwordConfirm)
{
    [].forEach.call([password, passwordConfirm], function(el) {
        el.addEventListener('input', function() {
            if ( el.validity.patternMismatch === false) {
                if ( password.value === passwordConfirm.value ) {
                    try{
                        password.setCustomValidity('');
                        passwordConfirm.setCustomValidity('');

                    }
                    catch(e){}
                }
                else {
                    password.setCustomValidity("The two passwords do not match");
                }
            }
            if ((password.checkValidity() && passwordConfirm.checkValidity()) === false)
            {
                password.setCustomValidity("The two passwords do not match, and they don't comply with the password rules.");
                passwordConfirm.setCustomValidity("The two passwords do not match, and they don't comply with the password rules.");
            }
            else
            {
                password.setCustomValidity('');
                passwordConfirm.setCustomValidity('');

            }
        }, false)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
<p>Password: <input type="password" required pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}" name="pwd1" onchange="
  this.setCustomValidity(this.validity.patternMismatch ? 'Password must contain at least 6 characters, including UPPER/lowercase and numbers' : '');
  if(this.checkValidity()) form.pwd2.pattern = this.value;
"></p>
<p>Confirm Password: <input type="password" required pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}" name="pwd2" onchange="
  this.setCustomValidity(this.validity.patternMismatch ? 'Please enter the same Password as above' : '');
"></p>
```

This will do the password and retype password fields validation.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/, if you don't mind using Jquery to do your dirty work.

Check out http://jqueryvalidation.org/equalTo-method

```
<form id="myform">
  <label for="password">Password</label>
  <input id="password" name="password" />
  <br/>
  <label for="password_again">Again</label>
  <input class="left" id="password_again" name="password_again" />
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Validate!">
</form>

<script>
  $( "#myform" ).validate({
    rules: {
      password: "required",
      password_again: {
        equalTo: "#password"
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

You can also write more complicated methods if required: http://jqueryvalidation.org/category/plugin/